# Multi-dimensional Array Initialization in C

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm piddling around with an Arduino and I have next to no programming in C.
In looking through some example code I came across this array variable declaration:

```
byte myArray[][6] = {"0"};
```

I get that this is declaring an array with unspecified rows and 6 columns.
What I don't understand is the {"0"}.
Upon the execution of this like of code, what will this variable contain?

Thanks!

Comment: The Arduino language is **Arduino-C++**, not C.

Comment: Just try `byte myArray[][6] = {"123456"};` - what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression will initialize an array that looks like this:

```
               myArray[0][0]
                     ^
                     |   +----> myArray[0][1]
                     |   |
                   +---+----+---+---+---+---+
myArray[0] ----->  |'0'|'\0'|   |   |   |   |
                   +---+----+---+---+---+---+
```

As you don't specify the first dimension and you only initialze 1 line it defaults to `byte myArray[1][6]`.

If you were to initialize your array with, for instance:

```
byte myArray[][6] = {"0", "1"};
```

Then it would be:

```
               myArray[0][0]
                     ^
                     |    +----> myArray[0][1]
                     |    |
                   +---+----+---+---+---+---+
myArray[0] ----->  |'0'|'\0'|   |   |   |   |
                   +---+----+---+---+---+---+
myArray[1] ----->  |'1'|'\0'|   |   |   |   |
                   +---+----+---+---+---+---+                    
                     ^    |
                     |    |
           myArray[1][0]  |
                          +--->myArray[1][1]
```

In this case, because you initialize 2 lines, it defaults to `byte myArray[2][6]`.

Answer (score 0):

The string literal `"0"` is equivalent to the compound literal `(char[]){ '0', '\0' }`. So the declaration is equivalent to:

```
byte myArray[][6] = { { '0', '\0' } };
```

So the resulting array will be one row that contains an ASCII `0` (or a `0` appropriate to whatever the target character set is) followed by 5 `\0` or NUL bytes.